# How to delete lines from list of tuples?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, tuples, n-gram

I have a code that prints a list with tuples with bigrams. For further word, I don't need bigrams that contain certain words. I have two different stop word lists that I want to apply to the bigrams. I want to apply one list to the first words of the bigrams (index[0]) and one list to the second words (index[1]).

I tried something like this:

```
if gram[0] in stop1 or gram[1] in stop2:
     print(gram)
```

Now the bigrams that DO contain the stop words are printed, but how can I remove these lines from the tuple?

Comment: Why not just use `filter` with a predicate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to print a tuple which has contents present in the stop-list, try this:

```
if gram[0] not in stop1 and gram[1] not in stop2:
     print(gram)
```

Comment: @S.H Accept the answer if it worked for you. It may help others. :)

Answer (score 1):

indexing your seach with a for i in range...

```
stopListA = [3,5]
myList = [(1,2), (3,4), (5,6)]
for i in range(len(myList)):
    if myList[i][0] in stopListA:
        myList[i] = myList[i][1]
print(myList)
```

[(1,2),4,6]